# How to staying responsive mobile menu active?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to use this menu on my web, but here have a problem, that is how to keeping the menu active?

I hope when the user browse the Home page, the menu bar will like this:
[image]

I found some example, like add the class ".active",
and put it in `<li>`, like:

```
<li class="active"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
```

But, it not working.

HTML:

```
<div class="rmm" data-menu-style='graphite'>
    <ul>
        <li><a href='#home'>Home</a></li>
        <li><a href='#about-me'>About me</a></li>
        <li><a href='#gallery'>Gallery</a></li>
        <li><a href='#blog'>Blog</a></li>
        <li><a href='#links'>Links</a></li>
        <li><a href='#sitemap'>Sitemap</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Here is the demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/7jgkzdf7/

Yesterday, I had been ask this question, however I make a lot of mistakes, I am sorry about that!
Now, I post again. Please help me to fix this problem!

Thanks!!!

Comment: You can do this in javascript. simply: document.getElementsByClassName('rmm') and then search array for the page it is corresponding to and add class('active'). I hope that helps.

Comment: i dont know what you want to do... add class active on your clicked <li> or do it responsive? ... because in jsfidle this menu isnt responsive

Comment: They want to set the active class on the page that the user is currently on. On page script for each page is the lazy way, then simply increment the array by 1 to add the active class to the correct page.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

JS:

```
$(".rmm ul li a").on('click', function () {
this.addClass('active');
});
```

CSS:

```
.rmm ul li a {
   url('http://responsivemobilemenu.com/demo/rmm-img/graphite-menu-bg-hover.png')
}
```

But this RMM (responsive mobile menu) is not good practice ... try to use Bootstrap. They have easy documentation and very good mobile first elements.
Try it here [Bootstrap](http://www.getbootstrap.com)